# PHP / DB2 Error on preparing statement

Tags: php, db2

I am getting this error when trying to db2_prepare() a statement with PHP 5.3.3

I've done other db2_prepare statements without error, any idea what might be wrong here?

"Error: 42601: Token '?' was not valid. Valid tokens: ROW ROWS. SQLCODE=-104"

This is the line of code I am having trouble on.

`$sql_featRand = "SELECT filine, fiitem FROM files.tablex ORDER BY RAND() FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY";

$db_prepRand = db2_prepare($dbConnection, $sql_featRand);
if ($db_prepRand === FALSE) {
echo "Unable to prepare statement- Error:  " . db2_stmt_error() . ": " . db2_stmt_errormsg();
die();
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you can't use a parameter marker in the `FETCH FIRST n ROWS` clause.  You have to specify a real value.

Unfortunately this means that you'll either have to prepare multiple statements or just stop fetching rows after reading the number of rows you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just doing "FETCH FIRST $limit ROWS ONLY" and preparing it with that. The variable isn't set by the user so I think it should be safe that way?

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be an issue.  Even if $limit were set by the user, it would only mean that the same statement might be prepared multiple times (with only the FETCH FIRST changing).

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a db2_execute statement that converts the ? in your prepared select statement to a number.